# ErrorException in helpers.php line 519: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

It says : (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lar\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

And my Welcome blade code is:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <ul>
                @foreach($errors -> all() as $error)
                    <li>{{$errors}}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be **$error** not **$errors** inside foreach loop.

Comment: Silly mistake I know, Anyways, Thanks :)